# How to scrape specific information on a website with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using the code below I am able to scrape data from a special website for football players of Bundesliga:

```
data = []
for i in range (1,12):
    URL = 'https://www.weltfussball.de/spielerliste/bundesliga-2021-2022/nach-name/'
    URL_ = URL + str(i) + '/'
    r = Request(URL_, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    #r = urllib.request.urlopen(URL_).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'lxml')
```

What I want to get is a pandas dataframe in which contains information of the players on this website, i.e. name, team, birth date, height and position. What I am now wondering about is the elements of the website that I have to specifically scrape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `pandas` for creating your `dataframe` - simply scrape table via `pandas.read_html()`, append it to your data and concat the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

data = []
for i in range (1,12):
    URL = 'https://www.weltfussball.de/spielerliste/bundesliga-2021-2022/nach-name/'
    URL_ = URL + str(i) + '/'
    response = requests.get(URL_,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    data.append(pd.read_html(response.text)[1])
pd.concat(data).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is really easy. I did not know about this very helpful function!